# How do i make the jspdf pdf file changes everytime an <option> tag in HTML is choosen?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm sorry that my english is pretty bad, and i'm an absolute beginner, but how do i make this work

````
    <html>
  <title>form</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script> 
<script type= "text/javascript">
   

   function genPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(45,45, "burgerking");
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0.25, 0.25, 210, 300);
doc.addPage();
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0.25, 0.25, 210, 300);
doc.addPage();
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0.25, 0.25, 210, 300);
if (document.getElementById("ice-cream").value == "choco") {
    doc.text(50,65, "please work")

}
else {
    doc.text(50,65, "knowing that you'll learn stuff when");
    doc.text(50,69, "failing miserably, you're filled with xd");

}


doc.save('form.pdf')
}
       

</script>


 <div>
<label>what kind of ice cream do you want?```<br>
<select id="ice-cream" onchange="genPDF()">```<br>
   <option value="vani"> Vanilla </option>```<br>
   <option value="choco"> Chocolate </option>```<br>
</select><br><br>
 </div>
````

obviously, the code wouldn't work, so could anyone please help ;-;

Comment: What is so "obvious" about this code not working? Assuming you got the PDF generation working in general already, I don't see what in particular should be wrong with how you tried to set different text based on the selection now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working code. Did you check the `imgData`. That is breaking the code. I just commented and its working. Also check last page of the Pdf.

````
<html>
  <title>form</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script> 
<script type= "text/javascript">
   

   function genPDF() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(45,45, "burgerking");
//doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0.25, 0.25, 210, 300);
doc.addPage();
//doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0.25, 0.25, 210, 300);
doc.addPage();
//doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG',0.25, 0.25, 210, 300);
alert(document.getElementById("ice-cream").value)
if (document.getElementById("ice-cream").value == "choco") {
    alert('ere');
    doc.text(50,65, "please work")
}
else {
    doc.text(50,65, "knowing that you'll learn stuff when");
    doc.text(50,69, "failing miserably, you're filled with xd");
}
doc.save('form.pdf')
}
       

</script>


 <div>
<label>what kind of ice cream do you want?```<br>
<select id="ice-cream" onchange="genPDF()">```<br>
   <option value="vani"> Vanilla </option>```<br>
   <option value="choco"> Chocolate </option>```<br>
</select><br><br>
 </div>
````

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I didn't know that the image data would be the main problem, guess i had to get a replacement. And you also upgraded my code, thank you!! Have a nice day!